# Angular Xeditable - Restrict row editing to one row at a time

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I am using AngularJS XEditable control for Inline edits. I would like to restrict the user to edit one row at a time. i.e. the user should not able to edit some other row when one row is in edit mode. Is there a way to check whether any row is in edit mode?

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: So far, the easiest way I've been able to do it is simply save the row currently being edited.  Since there is always some positive action (a click, a keypress, etc) that activates a row, I can deactivate the open row when another is activated (or disallow the new row to be activated).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, assign different e-form value for different rows you want to edit and show that on click as shown in the below code.

```
<td ng-click="goalValueForm.$show()"><span editable-text="data.goalValue"  e-name="goalValue" buttons="no"
                e-form="goalValueForm">  </span></td>
```